# Connected to On-prem Oracle Database from Azure

Tags: oracle, azure, biztalk

I have a web application running on azure and some of the data resides in my on-premises Oracle Database. I need a way to get that data from on-premises oracle database to that application running on azure.

I don't have any VPN connectivity to my On-Premises data center.

Can I use BizTalk Service in Azure?

Comment: What, exactly, is the issue? If you have firewall restrictions for your on-premises facility, you'll need to deal with those (since you don't have vpn). Regardless - this is off-topic for StackOverflow. Fits better on ServerFault.

Comment: Something like a Hybrid Connector? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview

Comment: @DavidMakogon I think firewall changes if probably what he is trying to avoid

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I get that. But aside from firewall opening/whitelist, VPN, or service bus / API type of technique, not really much else that can be done.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Except that there are things like the Hybrid Connectors that create outbound connections, which might mean no Firewall changes required. "Hybrid Connections require only outbound TCP or HTTP connectivity from your private network. You do not need to open any firewall ports or change your network perimeter configuration to allow any inbound connectivity into your network."  But you probably know more about that then I do ;-)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf correct - which is why I mentioned Service Bus (as there are published ways to work with a database across a service bus, as you brought up). Regardless: *Not a programming question*, as I originally stated.